# How to byte patch a longer hex/byte from the original?

Tags: ida

I am fairly new to IDA PRO I hope this is not some kind of stupid question but please bare with me. How do you change patch a hex/byte that is longer than the original?

Example:

[image: Text]

When I try to byte patch it, it will only save up to the last 00 on the original value and the rest are not saved or ignored.

How do you change the original value hex to a longer one?

Comment: Search for an unused area in the binary, place your patched code there. Then add a jump to the added code section and at it's end a jump back to the point where the original code is supposed to continue.